# How to print a number that is divisble by 4 working upwards (while loop) or awk

Tags: command-line, awk

I am facing a challenging issue in Linux where I need to print a number that is divisible by 4.

The following below helps me print an even number, but not divisible by 4:

```
echo 5 | awk -F, '$0%2{$0++}1'
```

Output:

```
6
```

I am not sure how to go about this, but perhaps if I use a while loop to add/increment to the initial value until the value can be divided by four then insert this value into a variable, which I can use.

For example:

```
val=5
5/4=  1.25 not divisible

val=val+1
val=6
6/4=  1.5 not divisible

val=val+1
val=7
7/4=  1.75

val=val+1
val=8
8/4=2 is divisible
```

Once the value is divisible by 4, echo the value 8 in this example to an output variable, not the answer, which is divisible by 4.

Comment: what if input is already divisible by 4? so for an input as `12` do you need output as `16` or `12`?

Comment: `echo 5 | awk '$0 % 4 { $0 += 4 - $0 % 4} 1'`

Comment: If for example the input is already divisible by 4, then no change is need, but in my case it is not a problem if it does output 16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
echo 5 | awk '{$0=int($0/4+1)*4}1'
```

Explanation:

- `$0/4+1` the value is divided by `4` and the result incremented by `1`.
- `int(n)` this is then rounded down by awks [`int()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html).
- `n*4` now we only have to multiply that with `4` to get the next higher number divisible by `4`.
- `{...}1` the `1` at the end will just print the value.

This will print `16` for the value `12`.

---

If you want the value to stay when it is divisible by `4`, then use this `awk` instead:

```
awk '{$0=int($0/4+.75)*4}1'
```

Comment: `int($0 / 4 + 0.75)*4` to just round up? (If I got it right, can't verify now)

Comment: @ilkkachu Good point, I code-golfed it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
i=5
while [ 1 ]
do
        if [ `echo $i%4 | bc` -eq 0 ]; then
                echo $i
                exit
        else
                i=`echo $i+1|bc`
        fi
done
```

Try this script with **while loop**